# Generator's excitation current - why do we need to know it?

Tags: current, generator

I dont undestand how seperately excited DC generators work.

If I remove the DC source doesn't that mean the generator will stop producing power?

And what is the excitation current? Won't the generator produce more power if I put a larger current at its input? With bigger input we will get bigger output right?

Comment: What equations are you using in your studies? Add some details into your question so we can see where the confusion lies.

Comment: I only understand that : \$E_{mf} = \kappa\Phi n\$ where \$\Phi \$ is the magnetic flux , \$ n\$ is the turns/sec and \$\kappa \$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Terminal voltage will rise with more exciter current (hence more flux), but unless the power supplied by the prime mover also increases the shaft speed will drop until a new equilibrium is found at a lower frequency where power output once again equals mechanical power input * efficiency.

Also, yes, if you shut down the exciter the terminal voltage theoretically goes to zero, practically there will be sufficient magnetism in the steel that you would not want to get across the output terminals of a big machine even with the exciter fully disconnected.

This is more subtle for grid connected alternators, where exciter current largely controls reactive power (and hence voltage) while real power is (dynamics aside) always substantially equal to mechanical power supplied to the machine.